# can not backup my h2 database with Backup.execute using java

Tags: java, jpa, h2

I want Backup h2 database files with Backup.execute("name.zip", "./data","mydb", true ), but getting following error : java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

I tried to close EntityManager em (em.close()) and EntityManagerFactory emf (emf.close()) then delete files but still getting same error. I tried to delete @persistencecontext from mainForm but still getting same error. this is my codes:

all of my codes are here:
[can not delete my h2 database files with DeleteDbFiles.execute using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546917/can-not-delete-my-h2-database-files-with-deletedbfiles-execute-using-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change my persistence.xml content like below and before take backup close EntityManagerFactory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>model.MycardsEntity</class>
    <class>model.PeymentsEntity</class>
    <class>model.WorkersEntity</class>
    <class>model.YourcardsEntity</class>
    <class>model.LoginEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:file:./data/mydata;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;FILE_LOCK=NO"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

now can use this code to take backup:

```
        emf.close();
    try {
        Backup.execute("./backup/name.zip", "./data", "mydb", true);
        System.out.println("done");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly opologize for the miss-understanding. What you have missed is the order of parameters. Which should be like below.

```
Backup.execute("/location/of/backup/file" + "/backup.zip", "./data", "yourdbname", true);
```

Comment: That's not true, H2 has online backup command. https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#backup

Comment: You say that backup cannot be taken when the database is in use in the **first version** of your answer. It's not correct, only the backup **tool** cannot be used when database is in use. The BACKUP **command** requires an active connection with ADMIN rights and it can be used instead. There are different instruments for different use cases.

Comment: Your edited answer is correct, because it explicitly mentions that the **tool** cannot be used. It does not say that online backup is not possible anymore.

Comment: it dose not let me to delete database files too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546917/can-not-delete-my-h2-database-files-with-deletedbfiles-execute-using-java

Comment: how can close main application then take backup?

Comment: @user9753394, I have updated my answer also deleted comments that were taking this discussion to nowhere. The snippet is an edited working code from my project.

Comment: i used code for backup, see my mainForm again. but i have error too. i try everything that i know, how can close main application then take backup??

Comment: Path of the backup file along with name is also required to take backup, which I have covered in my answer. In order to inspect the Issue you are expected to provide exceptions that you get that was not provided by you. You have mixed up two different questions here.  It is good to know that it worked. But to be honest, in first version of your question's resource files, there was not the code related to Backup. There was just the code for Restore. So, it was impossible for me to detect where it was wrong. Now please do not change you question at least. The issue was also with database path.

Comment: H2 online backup can also be taken without closing the SessionFactory or EntityManagerFactory. Clearing/closing the session is enough. "Providing exceptions" means to provide the complete exception log that is required to investigate the issue. So, it is a humble request try not to make fool atleast to yourself.

Comment: If closing the session factory / entity manager factory helps you it does not mean that you should always close it. There may be the issue with other part of the program where sessions are not properly closed / sessions are poorly handled.